# spring mvc 4: cannot location css

Tags: css, spring-mvc

When I load the page, there is no css there. And after I check the code and click the link for css, I got 404.
Is there something wrong with my configuration? I am a new Spring MVC user.

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix">
     <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
   </property>
   <property name="suffix">
     <value>.jsp</value>
   </property>
  </bean>
  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
</beans>
```

jsp file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
    <title>asdasd</title>
</head>
</html>
```

I also put my css file under resources/css/. Actually I am trying to load bootstrap.css, when I use CDN, it does not work. That why I am trying to load it locally. Unfortunately, it still do not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add below line in your spring config file.

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

And to access css from JSP use below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: In your way, it still does not work, I do not know why

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the URL needs to be prepended with a context?
Try this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.css"/>" type="text/css">
    <title>asdasd</title>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: could you then paste the logs after setting "org.springframework.web.servlet" to DEBUG level?

Comment: Sorry but I do not know how to set the DEBUG level. I am really new to spring mvc